# Hacer un filtrado con un rango finito con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Quiero hacer un autofiltrado a traves de VBA de una tabla con múltiples columnas.

Mi intención és que no filtre hasta el infinito, si no tener siempre yo el control sabiendo cual es el último registro de mi tabla.

Mi código és el siguiente:

```
last = Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(2, 1)).End(xlDown).Row

With sh ' Viene de un set. Se viene a referir a la hoja actual 
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range(.Cells(2, 20), .Cells(last, 20)).AutoFilter 20, "No" 'EL ERROR ME LO DA CON RANGE
End With
```

El error que me muestra el excel es el siguiente:
"Error en el método AutoFilter de la clase Range."

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás intentado filtrar por el campo nº20 con la palabra clave "No" pero no estás indicándolo en el código. Prueba a poner Field y Criteria1:

```
last = Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(2, 1)).End(xlDown).Row

With sh ' Viene de un set. Se viene a referir a la hoja actual 
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(last, 20)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="No" 
'IMPORTANTE: PONER Cells (1,20) si queremos que empiece por la fila 2, de lo contrario se saltará esta. 



End With
```

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo error. Pero creo que vba lo coge bien. Antes tenia este codigo " sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 20, "No" " directamente y no me daba error, pero me cogia hasta la ultima fila de la columna 20

Comment: Vale, creo que el problema es que intentas filtrar una única columna, la nº 20 y tú le estás diciendo que en ese rango (que consta de una sola columna) filtre el campo nº20 cuando realmente el campo es el nº1.

Cambia el 20 por un uno (1) y prueba.

Comment: Sí!! Funciono!!! Al parecer al poner .Cells(2,20) se salta la linea 2 y no la filtra. Lo he arreglado poniendo .Cells(1,20)!

Comment: Me alegro :-)

He modificado la primera respuesta cambiando el 20 por el 1. Márcala como respuesta correcta cuando puedas.

Gracias.

Comment: He editado tu publicación con el comentario de arriba pero necesita ser revisada por pares. Cambiala tu si quieres.